# @Autowired and UnsatisfiedDependencyException in a junit test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

i am writing a junit test that have to invoke some method from some autowired dependency which has to interact with Cassandra, but i am getting this exception:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.21 s <<< FAILURE! - in unicon.mattheews.admin.service.repository.test.AdminUserRepositoryTests
[ERROR] testFindByUsername(unicon.mattheews.admin.service.repository.test.AdminUserRepositoryTests)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'unicon.mattheews.admin.service.repository.test.AdminUserRepositoryTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'unicon.matthews.admin.service.repository.AdminUserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'unicon.matthews.admin.service.repository.AdminUserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

This is the junit test:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItems;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.data.util.Version;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import example.springdata.cassandra.util.CassandraKeyspace;
import unicon.matthews.admin.AdminUser;
import unicon.matthews.admin.service.repository.AdminUserRepository;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = CassandraConfiguration.class)
public class AdminUserRepositoryTests {

@ClassRule public final static CassandraKeyspace CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE = CassandraKeyspace.onLocalhost().atLeast(Version.parse("3.0"));

@Autowired AdminUserRepository repository;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    repository.deleteAll();
}

@Test
public void testFindByUsername() {

    try {
        final String userName = "aironman";
        AdminUser.Builder myBuilderAdmin = AdminUser.Builder.class.newInstance();
        myBuilderAdmin.withId("id");
        myBuilderAdmin.withEmailAddress("some@domain.com");
        myBuilderAdmin.withOrgId("orgId");
        myBuilderAdmin.withPassword("some-password");
        myBuilderAdmin.withSuperAdmin(Boolean.TRUE);
        myBuilderAdmin.withTenantId("tenantId");
        myBuilderAdmin.withUserName(userName);
        //que viene aqui exactamente?
        Map<String, String> someMetadata = new HashMap<String, String>();
        someMetadata.put("some-key","some-value");
        myBuilderAdmin.withMetadata(someMetadata);
        AdminUser myAdminUser = myBuilderAdmin.build();
        repository.save(myAdminUser);
        Optional<AdminUser> loadedUserName = repository.findByUsername(userName);
        assertNotNull(loadedUserName);
        // assertThat(repository.findOne(homer.id).isPresent(), is(true));
        assertEquals("something went wrong!",userName,loadedUserName.get().getUsername());
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Done testFindByUsername!");
}
```

}

AdminUserRepository looks like:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import unicon.matthews.admin.AdminUser;


@Repository
public interface AdminUserRepository extends CrudRepository<AdminUser, String> {

@Query("select * from AdminUser where username = ?0")
Optional<AdminUser> findByUsername(final String userName);

}
```

CassandraConfiguration looks like:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SchemaAction;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.java.AbstractCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class CassandraConfiguration {

@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories
static class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Override
    public String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "example";
    }

    @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.RECREATE;
    }
}
```

}

I understand that spring is trying to instantiate this AdminUserRepository class which is created using CrudRepository from spring-data project. It is supposed that if i mark this interface with @Repository, spring will instantiate the class within the spring context in order that another bean will be capable to autowire it within it, so, why spring is not able to instantiate the dependency?

AdminUserRepository interface is located within src/main/java and AdminUserRepositoryTests is located within src/test/java.

this is my actual [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/51uiT2iA), please help.

Comment: What packages are CassandraConfiguration and AdminUserRepository classes located at? Configuration shoud be "root" to all other classes.

Comment: CassandraConfiguration is located within the same package than AdminUserRepositoryTests which is src/test/java/some-package. The dependency AdminUserRepository is located within src/main/java/another-package. If i want to test this AdminUserRepository, ¿do i have to copy it into src/test/java/some-package?

Comment: That's could be an issue. Don't you mind to put CassandraConfiguration to src/main/java/some.package? And, as I told before, AdminUserRepository should be placed into src/main/java/some.package.another.one/

Comment: That is it! Now i am getting another exception: org.springframework.cassandra.support.exception.CassandraInvalidQueryException: unconfigured table adminuser; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table adminuser
but this is for another question... I think i have to create first the table adminuser within the selected keyspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking a Spring data repository with @Repository actually doesn't do anything. If you wan't to enable a CrudRepository you need to annotate your configuration with @EnableJpaRepositories. However, since you are using Cassandra I think it's more likely you want to be using a CassandraRepository ?

```
public interface AdminUserRepository extends CassandraRepository<AdminUser, String> {

@Query("select * from AdminUser where username = ?0")
Optional<AdminUser> findByUsername(final String userName);

}
```

Comment: Yes, it is more logical to use the CassandraRepository interface instead of CrudRepository. You are saying that i have to mark my CassandraConfiguration with @EnableJpaRepositories?

Comment: No that was just to get a CrudRepository bean set up. @EnableCassandraRepositories does it for a CassandraRepository afaik although I've not used Cassandra myself before.

Comment: If you watch CassandraConfiguration class, there is a CassandraConfig that extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration marked with Configuration and EnableCassandraRepositories. @Plog

Comment: Yes I know but I thought @EnableCassandraRepositories wouldnt work for a CrudRepository and only a CassandraRepository. I may be wrong though.

Comment: extending the repository interface with CassandraRepository and using a CassandraConfiguration class which has to be in the same package! Now i am getting the exception :  com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table adminuser

Comment: I'd make a new question for that to be honest. The Spring autowiring issue is now resolved at least.

Comment: `@Query` is not required using Spring Data Cassandra 1.5. With 1.4 and earlier, it was required. You don't need also to extend `CassandraRepository`, `CrudRepository` is sufficient.